# Close icon for close modal is not working

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, bootstrap-modal, bootstrap-vue

I am using bootstrap vue dialog package for confirmation message before delete or confirm any product. Every thing is work fine, But close icon on top right corner for close modal is not working correctly. when i click on close icon for close modal it did not work.
is there any property i need to add or i made some mistake?
please help me to correct my mistake.

areaconfirmed.vue

```
     async ConfirmArea(index){
                    let confirmArea = await this.$dialog.confirm({ text: 'Do you really want to confirm area?',title:'Confirmation',actions:{false:'Cancel',true:{text:'Confirm',variant:'primary'},},})
                        if(confirmArea){
                            axios.post('/admin/areaConfirmed/'+index,{
                                status:1,
                           }).catch(({response}) => {
                            this.$toast.error(response.data.message, 'Error', {timeout: 3000});
                        }).then(({data}) => {
                            this.$toast.success(data.message, 'Success', {timeout: 3000});
                            this.fetchUnconfirmedSellers();
                        });
                    }
                    },
```

app.js

```
    import Dialog from 'bootstrap-vue-dialog'
    Vue.use(Dialog)
```

Comment: It doesn't work in their official demo either, so it's most likely a problem with the plugin and not your code. You might be better off using plain [BootstrapVue modals](https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/modal#modal-message-boxes).

Comment: Yes, in official demo it also not work correctly.